# RotatingFileHandler Python 2.7 выводит в консоль

Tags: python, python-2.x, логирование, python-2.7

Есть такой код:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

logging.basicConfig(handlers=[RotatingFileHandler('log.log', maxBytes=100000, backupCount=10)],level=logging.INFO,format="[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s %(filename)s [%(name)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s",datefmt='%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')
logging.info('test')
```

Выводит в консоль, файл создается, но пустой. На Python 3.4 работает нормально. В чем может проблема?

Comment: Исправил код в вопросе.

Comment: Поддержка опции handlers появилась только в версии 3.3, и в версии 2.7 эта опция игнорируется

Comment: А для 2.7 придётся вручную создать formatter и добавить handler в root-логгер по аналогии https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/06a35542aad15666cace307d841a95e33f3cbee6/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L2003-L2007

Comment: А вообще поддержка 2.7 и 3.4 давным-давно прекращена, зачем они вам?

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать. Все написано на 2.7, перелопачивать в 3 долго (